# Can I specify a constructor value using the = operator?

Tags: c#, constructor, operators

When making a string in C#, you'd do `string foo = "bar";` string being a class, and the value "bar" got passed to the class using the `=` operator. How was that done? Could you do this in your own class?

I know this is doable in C++ as such.

```
class someClass {
public:
    someClass(int someInt) {
        // Do Stuff
    }

};

int main() {
    someClass classInst = 123;
}
```

But what would be the C# equivalent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two parts to this question:

- How string literals work
- How to do the same kind of thing for your own class

**String literals**

The expression `"bar"` is already a value of type `string`. The assignment operator here is just copying the reference, as it does for anything else. String literals cause string objects to be created where possible (but reused, so if you have that code in a loop, there's only a single `string` object). There's some subtlety here for interpolated string literals around `FormattableString`, but I'll ignore that for the purpose of this question.

---

**Creating your own literal-like syntax**

You can't make the assignment operator implicitly call a constructor directly, no. You *could* add an implicit conversion from `int` to `SomeClass`, but I would generally discourage that.

Here's a complete example in case you *really* want to do it, but it's really not idiomatic. By the time you have implicit conversions, you make it harder to reason about overload resolution for example - and anyone reading your code has to know that there *is* a user-defined implicit conversion.

```
using System;

class SomeClass
{
    public int Value { get; }

    public SomeClass(int value) => Value = value;

    public static implicit operator SomeClass(int value) =>
        new SomeClass(value);
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SomeClass x = 123;
        Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
    }
}
```

Note that if the [target-typed `new`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/100) feature comes to pass in C# 8, you'd be able to write:

```
SomeClass x = new(123);
```

... so you'd at least save the duplication there, even for fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can define implicit conversions between the two types: `int` and `SomeClass` like below:

```
// User-defined conversion from SomeClass to int
public static implicit operator int(SomeClass someClass)
{
    return someClass.SomeInt;
}
//  User-defined conversion from int to SomeClass
public static implicit operator SomeClass(int someInt)
{
    return new SomeClass(someInt);
}
```

Those methods should be defined in `SomeClass` declaration.

For more information about implicit conversion check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit).